# Next.js CSR on AWS ECS + Fargate GraphQL request doesn't work

Tags: next.js, amazon-ecs, server-side-rendering, apollo-client, aws-fargate

I'm developing application using Next.js and Golang with docker container.
On AWS ECS Fargate, Next.js CSR graphql request (query/mutation) dosen't work, but SSR works.
CSR request becomes time out.

Is there any solution? I would like you to tell me what should I do.

I think the reason why CSR time out is ALB on public subnet can't connect to ALB on Private subnet. Does Next.js SSR/CSR request use different IP ??

[Frontend]
Next.js + Apollo Client

[Backend]
Golang(Echo)

[Frontend request]
SSR(It works, can receive data from backend container)

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const { id } = ctx.query

  const input: FetchPostByIdQueryVariables = {
    id: Number(id),
  }
  const apolloClient = await initializeApollo(ctx)
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query<FetchPostByIdQuery, FetchPostByIdQueryVariables>({
    query: FETCH_POST_BY_ID,
    variables: input,
  })

  const post = data?.fetchPostById as Post

  return {
    props: {
      post: post,
    },
  }
}
```

CSR(Doesn't work, become time out)

```
const PostCreate: NextPage = () => {
  const [createPost, { data, error }] = useMutation<
    CreatePostMutation,
    CreatePostMutationVariables
  >(CREATE_POST, {
    onCompleted(data) {
      console.log('onCompleted', data)
    },
    onError(error) {
      console.log('onError', error)
    },
  })

  const onClick = async () => {
    const input: CreatePostInput = {
      title: title,
      body: body,
      image_url: 'tmp_url',
      is_public: isPublic == '1' ? true : false,
    }
    try {
      createPost({
        variables: {
          input: input,
        },
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('createPost err', err)
    }
  }
```

[AWS ECS Fargate Architecture]

【Public subnet】
(Security Group A)
ALB

↓

【Private subnet】
(Security Group B)
Frontend App(Next.js Apollo Client)

↓

【Private subnet】
(Security Group C)
ALB

↓

【Private subnet】
(Security group D)
Backend App(Golang Echo)

↓

【Private subnet】
(Security group E)
Aurora DB

Answer (score 0):

Your client-side-rendered (CSR) requests are running in the web browser of the client, not on AWS at all. It has nothing to do with "the ALB on the public subnet", because at that point the front-end ALB is not involved at all, it is purely a matter of the user's web browser/laptop being able to access the backend at that point.

In order for the user's web browser to be able to connect to the backend, the backend load balancer has to be in a public subnet, and it needs to have a security group that allows access from the Internet.

Having internal (VPC-only) private load balancers like your current configuration would only work with application architectures where **all** the traffic to those load balancers was happening from within the VPC.